# Lua as a stand-alone for game programming like Python?

Tags: software-engineering, lua

I've used Python before with PyGame to make games, but PyGame doesn't seem to be so popular anymore, and there arent that many good resources for it. I hear lots of buzz about Lua as a fast scripting language to be used inside of projects made in other languages.

I work much faster and enjoy the higher-level programming that is Python, so that naturally leads me to Lua, which seems to be getting a lot of attention recently. I know it's been around for a while but I think WoW add-on creation made it more popular..

Can Lua make games on its own as a stand-alone language with any 2D or 3D libraries, or is that not really the Lua domain?

I won't bother asking about 3D in Python here, I'll make a new question for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you're interested in developing games using Lua, I'd highly recommend checking out [LÖVE](http://love2d.org/) which is a framework for making 2D games in Lua. Checkout their [wiki](http://love2d.org/wiki/Main_Page) for lot of resources to get you started. :)

Comment: Incredible link and answer, thanks! Since we're here talking about and enjoying LUA, what possibilities are there for 3D? I see youtube videos of PSP stuff made in LUA so it must be possible, but not sure if it hooks to OpenGL or what. Any resources?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any existing 3D Lua frameworks worth recommending, but the process for constructing such a framework is the same as constructing a 2D one. Essentially you'd need to learn a programming language that can bind with Lua, and develop your framework in that language, creating the appropriate hooks for lua to access the functionality required. It's a pretty complex process, so it's not something I would dive straight into, but for more information on how to bind lua to different programming languages, check out: http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua

Answer (score 1):

for 3D try shiva

Comment: I'm pretty sure Shiva is more along the lines of something like Unity, and only uses Lua for scripting, not a stand-alone.